# How to get current login user name in qweb report odoo

Tags: odoo, openerp-8, odoo-9, qweb

I want to get and display `current login user name` in `qweb report` in odoo. Can someone please tell me, how can i do it or give me some example code. I'll be very thankful...!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **"user"** in your qweb template to get details of current login user, it is record of **res.users**.

To print the user name

```
<span t-esc="user.name"></span>
```

[Click here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/reports.html) to see more

Answer (score 10):

The `request` variable will always be available in a qweb context. You can use `request.env.user` object. Hence in a report, you can insert something like: `<span t-esc="request.env.user.name"/>`.